# Does the browser (Chrome/Firefox) automatically use https even when you try to use http?

Tags: html, google-chrome, http, firefox, https

I store urls in a database for the users of my webapp and I am not sure whether I need to store whether it was a "http" or a "https" request.

If I don't store the type of the connection and just echo to the users a link with "http", will it in 100% of the cases use a "https" connection automatically (when it is possible)? I don't want to be responsible for a user not using a https connection even though it is possible.

Comment: How will the URLs will be hit, via JavaScript and Ajax? Could you give an example use?

Comment: They will just be echoed via php into a <a>-tag in html.

Answer (score 2):

> Does the browser (Chrome/Firefox) automatically use https even when you try to use http?

**No.** If you tell the browser to use HTTP, then it will use HTTP.

Schemes will only be added to a URL automatically under two circumstances:

- When it is a relative URL, in which case the scheme will be the same as the one used to load the current document.
- When the user types the URL into the browser's address bar and omits the scheme, in which case it will default to HTTP (not HTTPS).

A web server **might** provide HTTP and HTTPS versions of the same URL with the HTTP version containing a redirect to the HTTPS version and the HTTPS version hosting the content.

A web server might, for that matter, not provide an HTTP version at all… but that is very uncommon.

> I am not sure whether I need to store whether it was a "http" or a "https" request.

You should store the full URL. You shouldn't omit bits and hope that you can fill them in by guesswork.

Comment: This answer is no longer accurate due to HSTS and HSTS preload. See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/166204/does-http-redirect-to-https-automatically

Answer (score 1):

It won't automatically do that, but there are ways to help out:

- some users may have the "HTTPSeverywhere" extension, which will attempt to redirect to HTTPS
- you can serve HSTS headers, which will make the browser automatically stick to HTTPS if the user has at least once been on HTTPS with your site

Now there are a few problems with these points:

- not everyone use the extension
- HSTS only works once the user was visiting the URL with HTTPS and it will only work on site with HSTS headers set up, so if links are external, this might not be the case.

That being said: Are the links you store links to your own domain or external links to any web site?

Comment: They are external links.